# How to check CentOS installation progress via virt-install method

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6, virt-install

I am trying to install centos-8 guest vm (over Centos 6.6 host) using kvm/qemu method (virt-install --graphics none) & remote ssh session using putty.

While installation is working successfully - I am unable to find method to check installation progress.

In virt-install text interface I can see options such as 1,2,3 ALT-F1 for help...). However, using putty, I am unable to use them (for example to check storage.log, etc.)

I tried seeking support on various blog posts but no luck. I wish to understand correct approach on how to check progress of virt-install text interface based installation (preferably using putty). I am also keep to know if any log file can be checked (generated by virt-install process) wherein I can see installation progress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick note. I am familiar with ~/.virtinst/virt-install.log which shows "kvm/qemu" progres. However, I am trying to understand actual OS installation progress.

Comment: Using putty would mean that an sshd server is up an running.  Looks to me that at that time, the installation is as good as finished.  Is ssh access mentioned in the installation guide you're following?

Comment: Hi, I am using putty to connect to "Host". From Host - I start virt-install for guest os. When I start installation of guest - I can only see & access 1st screen wherein I can see progress. However there are other options such as Alt+2, Alt+3...etc. which will further elaborate installation progress. How do I check that ? Please suggest.

Comment: Check putty preferences, if you can tell it to transmit these keyboard shortcuts to the host.  "other options such as Alt+2, Alt+3"  where did you find these options?